# GA-H170N-WIFI motherboard compatible memory

Tags: memory, motherboard, ecc

I bought [GA-H170N-WIFI](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5552#ov) and since it can handle 32GB of DDR4 I want to buy two 16GB modules but can't find them. I found some cheap 16GB modules selling at my location but they are marked Buffered (or ECC). I checked motherboard's specifications and this is what I found:

```
2 x DDR4 DIMM sockets supporting up to 32 GB of system memory
Dual channel memory architecture
Support for DDR4 2133 MHz memory modules
Support for ECC UDIMM 1Rx8/2Rx8 memory modules (operate in non-ECC mode)
Support for non-ECC UDIMM 1Rx8/2Rx8/1Rx16 memory modules
```

Will those 16GB ECC modules work or not?

Comment: Your motherboard will not accept 16GB ECC modules.  It says specifically in the specifications for the motherboard.  Gigabyte didn't test any 16GB non-ECC memory for a reason, likely because, there are no modules to test.  The specifications are crystal clear, your system, likely will not even POST with the 16GB ECC modules.  To be honest I am not sure how you are suppose to get 32GB if it won't even except 2 16GB non-ECC modules either.

Comment: You are looking for `16GB Crucial Ballistix Sport` modules.  They might not have been released yet.  But the part number assigned to them is a Crucial Ballistix Sport part number.  Even then your motherboard only supports one of those modules and they must be non-ECC

Comment: [Based on my research although the part-number does match the Ballistix Sport series Crucial is not selling 16GB modules](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/memory-ballistix-sport)

Comment: Ramhound what do you mean it supports only one module? it says I can get up to 32GB system memory. Anyway, thanks for all your comments

Comment: Anyway, when 16GB non ECC modules will be realeased will they work with that motherboard so I could build a 32GB pc?

Comment: Read the specifications.  It clearly indicates 1Rx16 which means it will only POST with a single 16GB module installed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with hardware stuff and those numbers. What I see is the line that says "2 x DDR4 DIMM sockets supporting up to 32 GB of system memory".  So is it possible or not? I want to build 32GB system on this motherboard.

Comment: Contact Gigabyte I suspect their specifications are incorrect since no supported combination of memory gets you to to 32GB

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing exactly what brand and spec the modules are, we wouldnt be able to answer that. However, on the support page for you mobo there is a link where you can download a pdf that contains a list of compatible modules. Here you go..

http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5552#memory%20support%20list

Comment: Yes, I tried to google any of 16GB modules in that list with no succes. I tried google by Modul P/N, supplier name and combination of words but can't find any of them. I even chatted with Crucial support but they gave me just a list of resellers like amazon etc. Still can't find 1x16GB DDR4 modules without ECC.